# Reuse Selenium method for 2 different cases

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium method defined as below. The method takes in personName string and tries to find in "li" element after removing any spaces.

Now I want to reuse the same method to check

> 1. without spaces (personNameWithoutSpaces )
> 2. with spaces (personName)

How do I update the below method to work for both the cases (since on one page, name can be rendered without spaces and in other page, it is rendered with space)?

```
public WebElement getPersonByText( String personName ) {
    String personNameWithoutSpaces = personName.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    return getHelper().getVisibleElement( By.xpath("//div[@id='display']//li[contains(@class, 'person') and contains(.,'" + personNameWithoutSpaces + "')]") ); 
}

public WebElement getVisibleElement( final By by ) {
        return getVisibleElement( by, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS, DEFAULT_TIME_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

Not sure if I need to use 2 try...catch blocks OR if I need to use if..else statement,,,

Comment: do you want use the method to check both (with and without spaces) for every page?

Comment: i want to write a generic method to check for both the cases...these are kind of diff pages...

Comment: is that mean if `personNameWithoutSpaces` exist then `with spaces (personName)` will not exist?

Comment: That is correct...for each check...only one of them will exist (with space OR one without space)

Comment: then how will you know `personName` contains spaces or not? And also you're using `String personNameWithoutSpaces = personName.replaceAll("\\s+","");` knowing it has spaces?

Comment: That's right...I do not have any way of knowing it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61757/discussion-between-vignesh-paramasivam-and-testndtv).

Comment: Id personally regex match and set a Boolean inside the method based on the match or not, and take action accordingly

Answer (score 0):

According to OP's comments,

```
 public WebElement getPersonByText( String personName ) {

    try{
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='display']//li[contains(@class, 'person') and contains(.,'" + personName + "')]") 
       return getHelper().getVisibleElement( By.xpath("//div[@id='display']//li[contains(@class, 'person') and contains(.,'" + personName + "')]") );

        }
     catch(NoSuchElementException e){
         String personNameWithoutSpaces = personName.replaceAll("\\s+","");
         return getHelper().getVisibleElement( By.xpath("//div[@id='display']//li[contains(@class, 'person') and contains(.,'" + personNameWithoutSpaces + "')]") );
      }

}
```

Comment: actually personName in the method would be the same...i have to write my logic considering this...

Comment: considering what? You mean you have a person name say `John Miller` and you have two pages where one page will have `JohnMiller` and other one with `John Miller`

Comment: i mean...i'll always pass personName as "my name is xyz"...but the rendering on the page can be either a) my name is xyz OR b) mynameisxyz

Comment: Got it. I edited my answer. Btw your question is little bit misleading though